# Como reconhecer o Entry selecionado

Tags: python, tkinter

Tenho duas entradas de dados(senha.entry,id.entry) e quero fazer com que o programa reconheça qual desses campos está clickado e inseria o valor que está dentro de um botão nesse campo selecionado.

[image: Tela]

Comment: Pelo que entendi, você quer um evento que seja ativo no momento em que os *entrys* sejam clicados. Dá uma olhada nos [eventos que pode usar no tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que o botão insira o valor no objeto, configure o comando dele de forma que:

```
Button(command=lambda: entry.insert(END,'1'))
```

Sendo '1' o valor a ser inserido. O processo seria o mesmo para os outros botões, alterando então somente o valor a ser inserido. Neste contexto eu o aconselharia a criar uma função que contivessem todos os botões de seu keyboard.

Para reconhecer qual dos objetos de entrada está em foco você usaria um bind do tipo `<FocusIn>`

Dessa forma o seus objetos de entrada poderiam associar-se ambas a uma mesma função que contesse as configurações dos botões, de forma que ao perceber qual delas está em foco, alterassem a qual **entry** elas devem se referir.

exemplo de sintaxe para o bind:

```
entry.bind('<FocusIn>', keyboard)
```